# Microsoft debug symbol don't work

Tags: c#, windbg, debug-symbols, pdb-files, memory-dump

I try to analyze some memory dump. But I stack on debug symbols of some Microsoft dll (`sechost.dll`).
What I do:

1) `!sym noisy`

2) `.symfix`

3) `.sympath`

My `.sympath` is:

```
Symbol search path is: srv*
Expanded Symbol search path is: cache*;SRV*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

4) `analyze -v`
After it I saw symbols loading.
But for some symbols I have

```
......
SYMSRV:  The operation timed out
SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/sechost.pdb/C4FD72A96E384F62A5F796624D37EAB42/sechost.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\sechost.pdb\C4FD72A96E384F62A5F796624D37EAB42\sechost.pdb not found
DBGHELP: sechost.pdb - file not found
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for sechost.dll - 
DBGHELP: sechost - export symbols
......
```

When actual analyze start I saw:

```
.....
IMAGE_NAME:  sechost.dll
BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS
FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS_80000003_sechost.dll!SubscribeServiceChangeNotifications
.....
```

I understand that I don't have PDB for this DLL. I try load it with `.reload /f sechost.dll`. But analyze got stuck on same place.
How to deal with this?
Maybe there is possibility to increase connection timeout or other way to get what I need?

Comment: Nothing better than opening a support case via http://support.microsoft.com

Comment: did you try .reload?

Comment: Another idea is to try opening the dump file with VS2015, maybe it will download the necessary pdb file.

Comment: That link returns HTTP 404 for me, so it seems it's just not available.

Comment: PDbs for yesterdays Win10 1607 cumulative update are missing. I already reported it to Microsoft.

Comment: I see latest symbols for 1607 update now. try again.

Comment: If symbols are available now, please self-answer your question, e.g. with the information of @magicandre1981 so that it can be marked as resolved (you can accept your own answer)

Comment: @ThomasWeller I posted what MSFT replied to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked this Microsoft and [Andy Luhrs](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/Andy+Luhrs) replied me that Microsoft needs 3 days to publish the symbols for new builds/ [Windows 10 updates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4000825).

So if you analyze dumps after updates have been published, try to load symbols 3 days after the update was published.

Answer (score 0):

Symbols was temporary unavailable on the server after cumulative update Win10 1607.
Microsoft already solved the issue.
Better solution in such kind of situations - report the issue to the maintainer.